# Proper Way to Create a NPM Package of Angular Services

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli, ng-packagr

I have an Angular 7 project that I am generating clients for (services / models) based off of a `swagger.json` spec. The generated clients reside in their own `api.module`. I would like to package these services and models using the Angular CLI, `ng build` and `yarn pack`.

> 1. What is the proper way to export services for a npm package?

Each service uses `@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })` and is ***not*** imported in the `api.module`. I have tried using a barrel or index file for the `services/` and `models/` directories but I am not able to **tree shake** the un-used services which is one of the main reasons for creating the package (i.e. mark it `sideEffects: false`.

**EDIT**

Thanks to a comment that unfortunately was removed, `ng-packagr` **CAN'T** use or work with barrels.

Are there any suggestions on how to *export* the services without barrels? Would I need to export each service in the `public_api` file?